# validation for semester duration

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I have semester table with 
sem_id, startmonth, startyear, endmonth , endyear, acadamic year, course fields

I want to do validation to check if the semester user is entering falls within existing semester duration.

For ex:I have in database   SemI starts June2010 and ends in dec2010
and one user is trying to enter semII starts nov2010 and end in may2011
then i need to give warning to user that semester II cant start before jan2011

thanks in advance for help

Comment: Do you have to do these operations using strings like June2010 and dec2010? Would a date field suffice?

Comment: thanks for reply. SemI starts June2010 and ends in dec2010 this is stored in database as june as it is 6 month 2010 and dec2010 as 12th month 2010 <br/>I am not storing "june" "july"...... strings but stored as 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5 and years are stored as strings 2010,2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to me there are number of ways for doing this task, I think the most easiest way to do this task is to give the user only options to select those months which have semesters, means only show him those months which are valid, do not show the others, Like you've semesters starting in June2010 and ending in Dec2010, Why you would like a user to enter other months and then prompt him, rather provide him in drop down the only semester months, hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Do not let the user enter the dates, rather provide him dates yourself, as i think what your last line tells you want to create new semester by let him enter dates, get the max end date from database and than increase one in it and load into drop down, ending with 6-7 ahead of this as you wish.

Comment: hi ther are drop downs for months and years